# FFMPEG: cut clips from a long video with "fast seek" while maintaining accuracy

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have this 3 hour long video which consists of <1-5 seconds of black frames> -- < clip > -- <1-5 seconds of black frames> -- < clip > -- ...

I could successfully get the clip without the black frames with the slow seek, but it takes over 4 minutes just for seeking.

`ffmpeg -y -i "C:\Users\user\Videos\obs\part1.mp4" -ss 4370.48 -to 4384.95 -c:a copy -c:v hevc_nvenc -rc vbr_hq -cq 19 -b:v 10000k -maxrate:v 12500k "C:\Users\user\Videos\obs\____delete1.mp4"`

I tried using the fast seek which takes only 4 sec, but it includes a 4 sec blackframe chunk at the end of the video. The output that should've been 14 sec long became 18 sec.

`ffmpeg -y -ss 4370.48 -i "C:\Users\user\Videos\obs\part1.mp4" -to 14.47 -c:a copy -c:v hevc_nvenc -rc vbr_hq -cq 19 -b:v 10000k -maxrate:v 12500k "C:\Users\user\Videos\obs\____delete2.mp4"`

My video has around 640 clips so it's impractical to wait that long just for seeking, and it'll only get worse when I'll be seeking at around the 2+ hour mark.

Comment: I don't see any evident error in your commands. Are you using the latest version of ffmpeg? It is always advisable to check that to discard the possibility of it being an error of a previous release.

Comment: You might get a faster Answer at [**SuperUser.com**](https://superuser.com/) since this about using a command line tool (& not a programming issue). There you can use your S.O account to click _"**Join This Community**"_ and then post a copy of your Question.